# Create a column out of the 2nd portion of text of two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns. I want to create a third column that is the 
"sum" of the first two columns, but without the first bit of each column. I think this is best shown in an example:

```
col1                col2                 col3 (need to make)
abc_what_I_want1    abc_what_I_want1     what_I_want1what_I_want1
psdb_what_I_want2                        what_I_want2
vxc_what_I_want3    vxc_what_I_want3     what_I_want3what_I_want3
qk_what_I_want4     qk_what_I_want4      what_I_want4what_I_want4
                    ertsa_what_I_want5   what_I_want5
abc_what_I_want6    abc_what_I_want6     what_I_want6what_I_want6
```

Note that what_I_want# will be different for every row, but the same between columns in the same row. The prefix will always be the same for each row but can differ/repeat between rows. Cells shown as blank are "" strings.

The code I have so far:

```
 df["col3"] = df["col1"].str.split("_", 1) + df["col2"].str.split("_", 1)
```

From there I wanted just the 2nd (or last) element of the split so I tried both of the following:

```
 df["col3"] = df["col1"].str.split("_", 1)[1] + df["col2"].str.split("_", 1)[1]
 df["col3"] = df["col1"].str.split("_", 1)[-1] + df["col2"].str.split("_", 1)[-1]
```

Both of these returned errors. The first error I think is because of replicated values (`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`). The second is a Keyvalue Error.

Comment: Why are you actually trying to do this though? What is the ultimate purpose with the new compound column? What does the `what_I_want` placeholder actually represent? e-commerce orders? latlon coords? Please give more context. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It sounds like dataframe merge/join or string concatenation got overused in the first place, if not this problem would not arise.

Comment: @smci I am trying to sort the rows by the values in `what_I_want` (col3). It is essentially a name. The prefixes contain information that is also needed in the end post sort, but I don't want to sort by. There is no overused merge/join/concat. There is no previous time when I have the values split into prefix/what_I_want, and aside from this one sort there is no future time when I want it split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually quite close, just needed to select the correct slice with `str[1]` and meanwhile `fillna` for the empty cells:

```
m = df['col1'].str.split('_', 1).str[1].fillna('') + df['col2'].str.split('_', 1).str[1].fillna('')
df['col3'] = m
```

---

```
                col1                col2                      col3
0   abc_what_I_want1    abc_what_I_want1  what_I_want1what_I_want1
1  psdb_what_I_want2                                  what_I_want2
2   vxc_what_I_want3    vxc_what_I_want3  what_I_want3what_I_want3
3    qk_what_I_want4     qk_what_I_want4  what_I_want4what_I_want4
4                     ertsa_what_I_want5              what_I_want5
5   abc_what_I_want6    abc_what_I_want6  what_I_want6what_I_want6
```

---

**Another method** would be to use `apply` where you can apply `split` on multiple columns at once:

```
m = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda x: x.str.split('_', 1).str[1]).fillna('')
df['col3'] = m['col1']+m['col2']
```

---

```
                col1                col2                      col3
0   abc_what_I_want1    abc_what_I_want1  what_I_want1what_I_want1
1  psdb_what_I_want2                                  what_I_want2
2   vxc_what_I_want3    vxc_what_I_want3  what_I_want3what_I_want3
3    qk_what_I_want4     qk_what_I_want4  what_I_want4what_I_want4
4                     ertsa_what_I_want5              what_I_want5
5   abc_what_I_want6    abc_what_I_want6  what_I_want6what_I_want6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `replace()` all char up until the first underscore and then `apply()` a `join()` or `sum()` on `axis=1`:

```
df['Col3']=df.replace('^[^_]*_','',regex=True).fillna('').apply(''.join,axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df['Col3']=df.replace('^[^_]*_','',regex=True).fillna('').sum(axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df['Col3']=(pd.Series(df.replace('^[^_]*_','',regex=True).fillna('').values.tolist())
                                                             .str.join(''))
```

---

```
                col1                col2                      Col3
0   abc_what_I_want1    abc_what_I_want1  what_I_want1what_I_want1
1  psdb_what_I_want2        what_I_want2       what_I_want2I_want2
2   vxc_what_I_want3    vxc_what_I_want3  what_I_want3what_I_want3
3    qk_what_I_want4     qk_what_I_want4  what_I_want4what_I_want4
4                NaN  ertsa_what_I_want5              what_I_want5
5   abc_what_I_want6    abc_what_I_want6  what_I_want6what_I_want6
```

Comment: Good ones  as well :)

Comment: These are good approaches as well. I accepted Erfan's answer since he was first and built off of what I had already.